# Can I use OAUT2 decorator for a user login to my app engine application

Tags: python, google-app-engine, oauth-2.0, decorator

I have a Python GAE application which presents the user with a HTML login page. This page includes an oauth2 login link (response_type=code) to login to my application. The link looks like this:

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.email+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.profile&state=%2Fprofile&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Foauth2-login-demo.appspot.com%2Foauthcallback&response_type=code&client_id=812741506391.apps.googleusercontent.com
```

After the user allows access, the GAE application receives a callback like:

```
https://oauth2-login-demo.appspot.com/oauthcallback?code={authorizationCode}
```

My questions:

- Can I use the Python oauth2 decorator to handle this callback = exchange the authorization code for an access token.
- Can I also use the decorator to create the oauth2 login link for my HTML page.

I'am using this flow: https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2Login.

And decorator: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/platforms/google_app_engine
Thanks for your help.

**UPDATE: I figured it out**.

login.py

```
from google.appengine.api import users
from oauth2client.appengine import OAuth2DecoratorFromClientSecrets

decorator = OAuth2DecoratorFromClientSecrets(
      os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'client_secrets.json'), 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email')


class LoginHandler(BaseHandler):

    @decorator.oauth_aware        
    def get(self):

        if decorator has credentials :
            http = httplib2.Http()        # verify audience using the TokenInfo API
            body = urllib.urlencode({'access_token': decorator.credentials.access_token})
            resp, content = http.request("https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo",method="POST", body=body)
            ....   # render template and show the user info from the TokenInfo response
        else:
            login_url = decorator.authorize_url()
            ....   # render template and show the login_url
```

And to handle the callback, I had to add two lines in my

app.yaml:

```
- url: /oauth2callback
  script: oauth2client/appengine.py

- url: .*
  script: login.py
```